# How to display real-time variables values in a Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, real-time

I wanted to `print` some real time messages and values in GUI in python with tkinter. As a newcomer I am not able to understand how to `print`. I've checked out so many answers, but they are not relevant.

Comment: First off in what python library, also you may wanna check both tkinter label and tkinter stringvar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't typically `print` data in `tkinter` apps — the data is instead displayed using one or more user interface "widgets" (like `Label`s).

But you can't really do it in "real time" — but you *can* periodically update instances of any the various kinds of [`Variable`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) classes `tkinter` has that the widgets in your user interface can be configured to refer to and update themselves from automatically.

The usual way to do the polling and `Variable` value updates is by using the universal widget [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to schedule this regular updating of the `Variable` class instances every so-many milliseconds.

There are numerous tutorials in books and on the web that show how to this can be done, as well as many answers here on SO. Many concern the updating of the display of a clock or stopwatch.